# how to modify tool tip in piechart,highcharts?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, highcharts, pie-chart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the X and Y axis names of Pie chart High Chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105829/how-to-change-the-x-and-y-axis-names-of-pie-chart-high-chart)

Hi all i have a pie charts where each slice shows a tool tip default which look like this

```
[Hr Resources:x=Hr Resources,y=12]
```

i want to modify this tool tip to

```
       [Project Name:Hr Resources,Logged Bugs:12]
```

i want the tool tip as show above ....

here is how i am binding  data to the pie-chart

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
      $.getJSON('<%= Url.Action("GetData","JqueryCharts") %>', {}, function (data) {
          var json = data;              
          var jsondata = [];              
          for (var i in json) {
             // var serie = new Array(json[i].Projects, json[i].Bugs);
              jsondata.push([json[i].Projects, json[i].Bugs]);
          }              
      var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
          chart: {
              renderTo: 'container',
              type: 'pie',
               plotBackgroundColor: null,
               plotBorderWidth: null,
               plotShadow: false
          },
           title: {
               text: 'Resource Reports of BugTracker'
           },              
          plotOptions: {
              pie: {
                  showInLegend: true,
                  animation: false,
                  allowPointSelect: true,
                  cursor: 'pointer'
              }
          },
          legend: {
              enabled: true
          },
          series: [{
              type: 'pie',
              name: 'Resource Reports',
              data: jsondata
          }]
      });
      });
  });
    </script>
```

Comment: Interesting that this is esentially the exact same question as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105829/how-to-change-the-x-and-y-axis-names-of-pie-chart-high-chart. Perhaps you all should flag this as homework?

Comment: @wergeld: Correct It has been answered by me.